# (400) Bad Request : Get AccessToken of Salesforce

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth-2.0, salesforce

I am trying to fetch all the contacts from **Salesforce** via **oauth** in my application. I am getting **The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.** when trying to get **access token** via API Token Url on my call back page. even When I have copy the URL and direct paste to the URL it is giving me correct data. but can't get the Access token.

I am using below method to Get **Access token**. Please experts suggest me where I am doing mistake. Same method is working fine for Google and LinkedIn.

```
public async Task<TokenResponse> GetAccessToken(string code,string tokenUrl,string consumerKey,string consumerSecretKey,string redirecturl)
    {

        string responseFromServer = "";
        var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(tokenUrl);

        const string queryStringFormat = @"code={0}&client_id={1}&client_secret={2}&redirect_uri={3}&grant_type=authorization_code";
        string contents = string.Format(queryStringFormat
                                           , code
                                           , consumerKey
                                           , consumerSecretKey
                                           , redirecturl);

        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        byte[] postcontentsArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contents);
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webRequest.ContentLength = postcontentsArray.Length;
        using (Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(postcontentsArray, 0, postcontentsArray.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (responseStream != null)
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        reader.Close();
                        responseStream.Close();
                        response.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(responseFromServer);
    }
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: What's the body of the HTTP response? That will usually explain the error.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by this: "even When I have copy the URL and direct paste to the URL it is giving me correct data" ?

Comment: while debugging I get the URL to get the Response. I have copy that URL and directly paste on browser it shows me correct XML with access token. But Gives the error in code.

Comment: With a browser you are doing a `GET` but your code is doing a `POST`. Are you sure the service requires form url encoded post body?

Comment: Yes, When I have tried it  Via GET method it gives error and said POST method required.

Comment: You are not URLEncoding the parameter values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm connecting to Salesforce without issue, but am using HttpClient instead of WebRequest.

```
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

            HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"grant_type", "password"},
                {"client_id", _clientId},
                {"client_secret", _clientSecret},
                {"username", _userName},
                {"password", _password}
            }
                );

                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var message =
                        await httpClient.PostAsync(_authorizationUrl, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    var responseString = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                    var obj = JObject.Parse(responseString);

                    var oauthToken = (string)obj["access_token"];
                    var serviceUrl = (string)obj["instance_url"];
}
```

Comment: I have made some changes in this as per my requirement. Thanks

Comment: working fine locally but after deployed on azure funtion getting 400 error

Comment: i'm facing same issue with this error -
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"authentication failure"}

Comment: question posted - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59651689/400-bad-request-get-accesstoken-of-salesforce-errorinvalid-grant