# (400) Bad Request : Get AccessToken of Salesforce error:"invalid_grant"

Tags: c#, azure, salesforce, azure-functions

I'm using azure function with below code -
everything is working fine when i run azure fucntion locally but after deployment i'm getting below error

> {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"authentication failure"}

Function code -

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "tokenURL");
                var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"));
                keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "clientID"));
                keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "clientSecret"));
                keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "userName"));
                keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "password"));

                request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);
                request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

                    string respContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var oauthResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(respContent);
                    string token = oauthResponse["access_token"];
```

> Is there any other setting required from salesforce ?
>
> Modify the Connected app: (Edit Policies) Relax IP restrictions
>
> Permitted Usersto "All users may self-authorize"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what we have in our Azure Functions that is working as expected. `ISalesforceConfigSettings` is not from any library, its our own hand written interface whose implementation(s) read values from Environment variables.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Salesforce access token given the client_id, secret, username and password.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="log">Tracewriter log</param>
    /// <param name="_settings">ISalesforceConfigSettings _settings</param>
    /// <returns>A Salesforce access token</returns>
    private async string GetSalesforceAccessToken(TraceWriter log, ISalesforceConfigSettings _settings)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        // Create Request Body
        var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", _settings.SalesforceClientId),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", _settings.SalesforceClientSecret),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", _settings.SalesforceUserName),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", _settings.SalesforcePassword),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", _settings.SalesforceGrantType)
        });

        try
        {
            // Call to get access token
            var loginResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(_settings.SalesforceLoginUrl, formContent);
            var loginResponseString = await loginResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // Log Login Response
            log.Info(loginResponseString);

            // Extract Access Token
           return JsonConvert
                .DeserializeObject<SalesforceLoginResponse>(loginResponseString)
                .AccessToken;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Just in case if you're wondering what is `SalesforceLoginResponse` class is...

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Models.Salesforce
{
    public class SalesforceLoginResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty("access_token")]
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: No luck for me :(
is there any other setting you did at salesforce side like 
Modify the Connected app: (Edit Policies)
Relax IP restrictions
Permitted Users to "All users may self-authorize"

Comment: No IP restrictions (aka set to Relax), Permitted Users IS set to "All users may self-authorize". Probably dumb questions, did you check the login URL, is that set correctly? also, do you have the security token appended to the password? For a short period we were getting invalid_grant error cos we were not appending the security token to the password.